# AMD Catalyst Drivers 14.9 needs kernel-headers on 14.10, altough it is missing a version for Utopic

Tags: drivers, kernel, ati, radeon, fglrx

Within the release of Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn I've decided to upgrade for it, in hope of better support to my graphics card from AMD, because in the release notes of both Catalyst and Ubuntu it was promised better graphical support. Besides that, when I try to run the installer that comes with the zip file, it reports me in the installation log that it needs the kernel headers from the version, and recommends me installing the package linux-generic, but that version is 2.16. I've heard of getting the kernel's source code and extracting it, but I haven't found any tutorials on the web for it. And when I try to install linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic, it reports me that the package is only avaiable for trusty and trusty-updates. And no, I'm not using fglrx or fglrx-updates because Unity nor Gnome won't load, instead showing a black screen and the only thing that would display things are the tty's.

Currently I am using the XOrg XServer's drivers, but that is very restricting, as alot of 3D apps depends on fglrx or advanced drivers.

Anyone knows how to fix this, be it by means of downloading the kernel's source code from kernel.org or other ways?

My graphics card is AMD Radeon HD 6310 and my architethure is x86_64.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

After the failed boot up, logging in to the TTY and running

```
sudo startx
```

shows an error with the symbolic link to /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libglx.so - not found.

I created the symbolic link, but this did not solve the problem.  Currently unable to get startx to function using Catalyst 14.9 on Utopic 14.10.

I know that utopic was waiting on Catalyst with support for xorg 1.16 back in September and it's said it was there, but the 14.9 driver you download from the site still shows support up to xorg 1.15 only.  Not sure if this is the source of the issue or not.

I know that the installer allows you to package for Ubuntu/utopic, and install it using dkpg.. but this didn't make any difference either.

Any thoughts?  I upgraded for the same reasons (graphical support) as the OP. I use an MST hub for 3 monitors and the open-source-tested (non-fglrx) driver doesn't natively support MST through DP-1.2.  Would be really nice to get back to my 3 monitors.

Thanks.

Comment: Some days ago, the upgrader showed me up that now the kernel headers for development are included, and I will try to install and see if it works.

Comment: I'm still stuck at two monitors.  Everything I've tried has come up fruitless. I am debating using a new hard drive to do a fresh install and see if anything is erroring due to legacy issues.  If that doesn't work, I may do a re-install of 14.04 for now.  At least there I could get 3 monitors even if slightly buggy.

Comment: The installer worked, but... Black screen occoured. I've solved it by running the amd-uninstall.sh with the --force argument; Although I can't recall where it is, do: `cd /` then `find | grep amd-uninstall.sh`