# Blank screen on booting ubuntu

Tags: ati, 14.10

I was trying to install amd graphics drivers and after rebooting now I get just a blank black screen.Someone please help urgently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your problem with the graphics driver from the black screen. The following five topics are useful things to know about how to solve a blank screen problem that occurred after installing the AMD graphics driver in Ubuntu 14.10.

1. To bring up a text-only console use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and then you will get a text-only console which shows you a login prompt. Two other useful things to know about the console are: the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to move away from the console and the command `sudo reboot` to reboot the computer.
2. To uninstall the proprietary graphics driver (if it was downloaded from the official AMD website) from a text-only console, login and run the command: `sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh` and reboot the computer. [Removing Catalyst/fglrx](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Trusty_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx) says if fglrx-uninstall.sh doesn't exist use: `sudo apt-get purge fglrx*` and reboot to uninstall the graphics driver from the AMD website manually. The same command `sudo apt-get purge fglrx*` is also used to uninstall the proprietary AMD graphics driver if it was installed from the Ubuntu repositories.
3. To start the Additional Drivers utility from the desktop environment search for *Additional Drivers* in the Dash and click the Additional Drivers icon.
4. There is also a text-only terminal program to show the available graphics driver packages. From the terminal or from the console run: `ubuntu-drivers devices`. This command will often also identify the recommended proprietary graphics driver for your system. Wait for at least a minute after entering the command for the operating system to scan your hardware.
5. [AMD Catalyst Drivers 14.9 needs kernel-headers on 14.10, although it is missing a version for Utopic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541469/amd-catalyst-drivers-14-9-needs-kernel-headers-on-14-10-altough-it-is-missing-a). This is another reason to choose a proprietary graphics driver from the Ubuntu repositories instead of downloading it from the official AMD website.

Hopefully some of these tips will help you to get this issue sorted out. In Ubuntu everything you need to do to install, uninstall or get information about a graphics driver can be done from a terminal or from a text-only console, so if you make a mistake you can fix it, even if you can't login to your graphical desktop environment.